Select with virtual table
Can someone please explain what is coded here? I do not understand the reason for the select statements in brackets and the name of that query (M1,M2) behind that. I was told the second line defines a virtual table.
The result of the query shows two columns with the data of VAR1 from dbo.mydata and VAR2 from dbo.yourdata.
select * from (select VAR1 from dbo.mydata) M1,
(select VAR2 from dbo.yourdata) M2 
where VAR1 = VAR2


A subquery in the FROM clause is called derived table.

Tip of today: Use modern, explicit JOIN syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Also, tip 2, it's good programming practice to qualify all columns. E.g. M1.VAR1 instead of just M1.

Thank you, jarlh. This helped me find relevant documentation to understand this!

In the FROM clause we state which tables to select from in the query. But these tables don't have to be tables stored in the database, they can also be views or query results.
In order to select from a query result, we must put the query in parentheses, thus making it a subquery. In your main query you select from two subqueries (aka derived tables). The query uses an old join syntax that was used until the SQL standard of 1992 provided explicit joins ( [INNER] JOIN, LEFT [OUTER] JOIN, etc.) which made the old join syntax redundant.
So, you are selecting two data sets and then you join them on equality of their two columns. Nowaday we would either write this as
SELECT *
FROM 
  (SELECT var1 FROM dbo.mydata) m1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT var2 FROM dbo.yourdata) m2 
ON m2.var2 = m1.var1;

or
WITH
  m1 AS (SELECT var1 FROM dbo.mydata),
  m2 AS (SELECT var2 FROM dbo.yourdata)
SELECT *
FROM m1
INNER JOIN m2 ON m2.var2 = m1.var1;

provided this is just a simplified example. If this is the real query, we would use no subqueries at all, because both select all rows from the tables. We would just write:
SELECT m1.var1, m2.var2
FROM dbo.mydata m1
INNER JOIN dbo.yourdata m2 ON m2.var2 = m1.var1;

(And as m1.var1 = m2.var2, we would select only one of the columns, and depending on whether the values can occur once or more in the tables, we might rather use IN or EXISTS than joins to get a distinct list. But this is not what you asked, so I stop here ;)
